# Retrieve index and columns from specific values in a pandas dataframe

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

Suposing the dataframe below, called `df`.
How could I get a list of tuples pointing to the index and columns where the values are equals `1`?

```py
     0  1  2  3  4  5  6  7  8
0    4  4  0  3  0  2  0  1  3
1    3  3  3  0  0  0  3  4  3
2    0  3  0  3  3  3  0  3  0
3    4  0  3  5  4  6  3  0  3
4    0  0  2  4  0  3  2  0  0
5    3  0  3  4  3  6  3  0  2
6    0  2  0  3  1  2  0  2  0
7    4  3  4  0  0  0  3  2  3
8    3  3  0  4  0  3  0  3  2
```

My desired result would be the following list: `result = [(6,4), (0,7)]`. The first number `1` is found at coordinates `6,4` and the seccond one at `0,7`. The order of the tuples doesn't matter at all.

I've tried to use `df[df.values == 1]`, but it only filter the rows that have the number `1`, and that's not what I desire.

Please notice that the number `1` is not the `min` or `max` value, the methods `.idxmin()` won't work here.

The number `1` keeps changing place, just need to localize its coordinates in an automated way.

Comment: This is perhaps a duplicate and `[*zip(*np.where(df.eq(1)))]`.

Comment: We first find *where* the dataframe takes values *eq*ual to 1 and then manipulate the result a little with *'s and `zip` to get the desired form.

Comment: The `where` is good, so long as you have a RangeIndex on the rows and columns, else you'll get the array-locs and not the labels (could be more preferable though)